# Addition and scalar Multiplication operations defined on a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Are the theorems in linear algebra true for only those vector spaces where addition and scalar multiplication is defined in traditional sense, with $0$ as the additive identity and $1$ as the scalar multiplicative identity. In  proofs of  some of the theorems we make use of $0$ as additive identity and $-1(x)$ as additive inverse.

Comment: Vector spaces are any space that obey the vector space axioms. They will always have a $0$ vector and a $1$ scalar but what those elements are can vary. Even the $0$ element in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are defined differently but they still act in the same way, as the additive identity.

Comment: To expand on @CyclotomicField's comment, any space satisfying the vector space axioms will satisfy any theorem about vector spaces, no matter how bizarre or abstract the additive or multiplicative identities appear.

Comment: There are important theorems in linear algebra that only apply where addition and scalar multiplication is only defined over real/complex numbers, but in general linear algebra will work over any field (such as finite fields).